# Data Validation

Tags: cobol

So I have entered my second semester of College and they have me doing a course called Advanced COBOL. As one of my assignments I have to my make a program that tests certain things in a file to make sure the input has no errors. I get the general idea but there are just a few things I don't understand and my teacher is one of those people who will give you an assignment and make you figure it out yourself with little or no help. So here is what I need help with.

1. I have a field that the first 5 columns have to be numbers, the 6th column a capital letter and the last 2 numbers in a range of 01-68 or 78-99.
2. one of my fields has to be a string of numbers with a dash in it like 00000-000, but some have more than one dash. How can I count the dashes to identify that there is a problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Are you looking for help with understanding the concepts or with the implementation?

Comment: I have mostly been thinking of how to work this problem. I think I have a solution for my second question though. If I move the record with the information I have to check to a different field, putting each column in it's own record I can check them 1 by 1 and add up the total of dashes.This way sounds a bit complex and I am sure there is an easier way to do this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few hints...

Use a hieratical record structure to view the data in different ways. For example:

```
 01 ITEM-REC.
    05 ITEM-CODE.
       10 ITEM-NUM-CODE    PIC 9(3).
       10 ITEM-CHAR-CODE   PIC A(3).
          88 ITEM-TYPE-A   VALUE 'AAA' THRU 'AZZ'.
          88 ITEM-TYPE-B   VALUE 'BAA' THRU 'BZZ'.
    05 QUANTITY            PIC 9(4).
```

`ITEM-CODE` is a 6 character group field, the first part of which is numeric (ITEM-NUM-CODE) and the last part
is alphabetic (ITEM-CHAR-CODE). You can refer to any one of these three variables in your program. When you
refer to `ITEM-CODE`, or any other group item, COBOL 
treats the variable as if it were declared as `PIC X`. This means you can
`MOVE` just about anything into it without raising an error. For example:

```
MOVE 'ABCdef' TO ITEM-CODE
```

or

```
MOVE 'ABCdef0005' TO ITEM-REC
```

Neither one would cause an error even though the elementary data item `ITEM-NUM-CODE` is definitely not a number. 
To verify the validity
of your data after a group move you should validate each elementary data item separately (unless
you know for certain no data type errors could have occurred). There are a variety of ways to do this. For
example if the data item has to be numeric the following would work:

```
IF ITEM-NUM-CODE IS NUMERIC
   CONTINUE
ELSE
   DISPLAY 'ITEM-NUM-CODE IS NOT NUMERIC'
   PERFORM BIG-BAD-ERROR
END-IF
```

COBOL provides various class tests which can be applied against a data item. For 
example: NUMERIC, ALPHABETIC and ALPHANUMERIC are commonly used.

Another common way to test for ranges of values is by defining various 88 levels - but exercise
caution. In the above
example `ITEM-TYPE-A` is an 88 level that defines a data range from 'AAA' through 'AZZ' based on
the collating sequence currently in effect. To verify that `ITEM-CHAR-CODE` contains only alphabetic
characters and the first letter is an 'A' or a 'B', you could do something like:

```
IF ITEM-CHAR-CODE ALPHABETIC
   DISPLAY 'ITEM-CHAR-CODE is alphabetic.'
   EVALUATE TRUE
      WHEN ITEM-TYPE-A
         DISPLAY 'ITEM-CHAR-CODE is in range AAA through AZZ'
      WHEN ITEM-TYPE-B
         DISPLAY 'ITEM-CHAR-CODE is in range BAA through BZZ'
      WHEN OTHER
         DISPLAY 'ITEM-CHAR-CODE is in some other range'
   END-EVALUATE
ELSE
   DISPLAY 'ITEM-CHAR-CODE is not alphabetic'
END-IF
```

Note the separate test for `ALPHABETIC` above. Why do that when the 88 level tests
could have done the job? Actually the 88's are not sufficient because they
cover the entire range from `AAA` through `AZZ` based on the collating sequence currently
in effect. In
an EBCDIC based environment (a very large number of COBOL shops use EBCDIC) this captures
values such as `A}\`. the close-brace and backslash characters are non-alpha but 
fall into the middle of
the range 'A' through 'Z' (what the #*@! is that all about?). Also note that a value such 
as 'aaa' would not satisfy the `ITEM-TYPE-A` condition because lower case letters fall outside 
the defined range. Maybe time to check out an EBCDIC character table.

Finally, you can count the number of occurrences of a character, or string of characters, in
a variable with the `INSPECT` verb as follows:

```
INSPECT ITEM-CODE TALLING DASH-COUNT FOR ALL '-'
```

`DASH-COUNT` needs to be a numeric item and will contain the number of dash characters in `ITEM-CODE`. The `INSPECT`
verb is not so useful if you want to count the number of digits. For this you would need one statement for each digit.

It might be easier to just code a loop something like:

```
PERFORM VARYING I FROM 1 BY 1
           UNTIL I > LENGTH OF ITEM-CODE
   EVALUATE ITEM-CODE(I:1)
      WHEN '-'
         COMPUTE DASH-COUNT = DASH-COUNT + 1
      WHEN '0' THRU '9'
         COMPUTE DIGIT-COUNT = DIGIT-COUNT + 1
      WHEN OTHER
         COMPUTE OTHER-COUNT = OTHER-COUNT + 1
   END-EVALUATE
END-PERFORM
```

Now ask yourself why I was comfortable using a zero through 9 range check? Hint: look at the collating sequence.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, that looks like it is a bit ahead of what we are doing, but it does help a bit cause I needed to use that inspect statement. I am afraid though I have encounter two new problems, but I actually have something written out now. I am (sorta) new to this site so I don't know whether I should edit this post or start a new one.

Comment: @Kimmy1235 Editing the original question or posting a new one are both valid options. Edit the question if you are trying to clarify some aspect of the original question or the answers you were getting were off track. Post a new question if the orginal question was answered and the new question does not need to refer to the first one. Also, don't be in a rush to accept answers - only accept an answer if you are satisfied with it. Some questions are never properly answered.